# laravel 5.2 Database doesn't store through store method in contorller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I want to store some data through my form input. But while i submit the save button instead of saving the data it redirect to some other page. Anyone who find the problem, please provide a good solution.

Here is my routes.php

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    });

   Route::resource('test','TestController');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Here is my Test Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Test;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Redirect;

class TestController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
    {
            $alldata=Test::all();   
            return  view('test.itemlist',compact('alldata'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
            return view('test.create_item');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {                
            $input = $request->all();
            Test::create($input);       
            return redirect('/tasks');
    }
}
```

And here is the view page :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Create Item</div>
                {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'test/store','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
                {!! Form::token(); !!}
                  <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Item Code</label>
          <input type="text" name="item_code" class="form-control"  placeholder="Code">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Item Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name">
        </div>        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
               {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is my migration Table Code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('test_id"');
            $table->string('item_code');
            $table->string('item_name');           
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And the Test Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table="tests";
    protected $primaryKey="test_id";
    protected $fillable=['item_code','item_name'];
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error for mass-assignment within Laravel you need to define `protected $fillable = ['column_name1','column_name1'];` within your `Test` model class

Comment: I have already defined my Test Model with fillabale array

Comment: Both migration and model look fine. Post a result of `dd($request->all());` executed in store method please.

Comment: Define what "some other pages" means?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: actually in store method by mistake i have put

```
 return redirect('/tasks');
```

instead of

```
return redirect('/test');
```

BTW thank all of you who have tried so far.